# How to visually show that a preference options are disabled?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have created a 'Preferences' file in which I have a CheckboxPreference . When I uncheck the CheckboxPreference its dependants are getting disabled. However, it doesn't leave any visual clue that these dependants are disabled. How to provide that?

Comment: All dependent controls are clearly disabled.

Comment: I know that's disabled by default, what i really mean is, if the text color is black when its in enable state, i want that to be in grey color when its disabled. (eg:I need, As what it happens when we disable the textview)

Answer (score 0):

Try to show some alert dialogue or Toast message in onSharedPreferenceChangedListener() in your preference activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a reference to your Preference in your PreferenceActivity using `findPreference` method then set `preference.setShouldDisableView()` to true and `preference.setEnabled()` to false and see if it helps.

Comment: `findPReference ()`is **deprecated**, and so is `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein ok...  even if I change it to preference fragment its not working for me. I want to grey out the preference when it is disabled. What would you like to suggest me in this regard?

Comment: As I said, when a preference is disabled, it's **visually explicit** that it's disabled http://android-journey.blogspot.it/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html

Comment: @FrankN.Stein actually i want like what's shown in your link's screen shot. But its not working in the same way in my code. Text color is not changing .

Comment: Not working here also.. Did someone find a solution for this?

Comment: If this answer doesn't work check if you use the right colors in your theme. You should use selectors for primary/secondary colors instead of "pure" colors.